# Pointer to Node doesn't update Node properties

Tags: c++, class, pointers, tree

I have a BinaryTreeNode class, which among other things has two children Left and Right.

I want to instantiate a node N, give it two children L and R, *then* update the properties of those children so that those properties are reflected when I access them through N later on: N.getLeft().getName() should be the same as L.getName().

What I have instead is L and R properly updated, but when accessed through N, they're not.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the class declaration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class BinaryTreeNode
{
public:
    BinaryTreeNode();
    BinaryTreeNode(std::string newName);
    BinaryTreeNode(std::string newName, BinaryTreeNode Left, BinaryTreeNode Right);
    ~BinaryTreeNode();

    BinaryTreeNode getLeft();
    BinaryTreeNode getRight();
    int getValue();
    std::string getName();
    void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode newLeft);
    void setRight(BinaryTreeNode newRight);
    void setValue(int newValue);
    void setName(std::string newName);

private:
    int value;
    std::string name;
    BinaryTreeNode* Left;
    BinaryTreeNode* Right;
};
```

And main:

```
#include "tree.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    BinaryTreeNode N("N"), L, R;
    BinaryTreeNode *Lptr, *Rptr;
    Lptr = &L;
    Rptr = &R;
    N.setValue(45);
    N.setLeft(L);
    N.setRight(R);
    Lptr->setName("L");
    Rptr->setName("r");
    Lptr->setValue(34);

    std::cout << "Name of N:" << N.getName() << std::endl; //N
    std::cout << "Name of L:" << L.getName() << std::endl; //L
    std::cout << "Name of R:" << R.getName() << std::endl; //r

    std::cout << "value of N: " << N.getValue() << std::endl; //45
    std::cout << "name of N left: " << N.getLeft().getName() << std::endl; //nothing, instead of "L"
    std::cout << "name of L: " << L.getName() << std::endl; //L
    std::cout << "value of N left: " << N.getLeft().getValue() << std::endl; //0, instead of 34
    std::cout << "value of L: " << L.getValue() << std::endl; //34
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Pass strings by const reference.You can probably return the string from getName by const reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mess of pointers and copies by values:

```
N.setValue(45);
N.setLeft(L); //This create a New instance of L, copies  the original by value, and then sets it as the left node, eg, its a new node
N.setRight(R); // The same
```

you should pass pointers in the case:

```
void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode * newLeft);
void setRight(BinaryTreeNode * newRight);
```

this way, when you edit the nodes, they will be changed.
Else you just create new instances.

Answer (score 1):

How do you initiate the Left and Right? Maybe the setLeft and setRight stores the address to the temporary memory of the parameter? It is though hard to say without the `BinaryTreeNode` methods' implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`setLeft()` and `setRight()` are both taking the node by value.  This breaks any connection from the nodes in main and the nodes inside the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
N.setLeft(L);
```

And this is setting the Left Node to the value of 'L' (not the address of 'L') which hasn't been instantiated yet.  You are then setting the name of 'L' to it's address by doing:

```
Lptr->setName("L");
```

So when you access N.getLeft() you are accessing uninitialized memory and therefore doing N.getLeft().getName() is basically undefined and you could get junk.

change your code to N.setLeft(&L);